# RxJava async subscribe will lost message

Tags: rx-java2

I was learning how RxJava async subscribe works. But some problem confused me.

```
@Test public void testCreateAsync() throws InterruptedException {
  Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
        int finalI = i;
        new Thread(() -> emitter.onNext("value_" + finalI)).start();
      }
    }
    if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
      emitter.onComplete();
    }
  });

  observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

The code above works fine, and print `value_1` to `value_9`. But when I add a sleep before subscribe, the last message `value_9` will not be printed,like this:

```
@Test public void testCreateAsync() throws InterruptedException {
  ...
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Any discusses about this question is appreciate.

ps: java version is `1.8`, and RxJava version is `2.1.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. calling `onNext` from different threads concurrently
2. `onComplete` may execute before the previous threads are able to emit their value which prevents any further `onNext` emissions.

The sleep has no particular effect, repeatedly executing the code above will sometimes yield the behavior.

(It's unclear to me what you wanted to achieve with this setup).

Comment: It's actually meaningless, just a demo. Thanks for your answer. I ignored the concurrent problems.